# Is it possible to embed Windows forms in WPF Web application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I'm building an application that will be hosted on web with WPF. I got some legacy forms in old Windows Forms application, is it possible to embed those, or I will have to rewrite them?

I know I can embed them easily in desktop WPF applications.

Comment: Why are you using WPF for web applications?  XBAP is problematic at best...

Comment: It was a specific client request..

Comment: @AngelaNovak Did you provide your client an advice?  You shouldn't just say, "Okay!" and take their money.  Advise them of the best route.

Comment: @AngelaNovak I'd focus on educating the client.  They're going to run into many problems this way.

Comment: They are not willing to pay rewrite the project, because they have working windows forms application. We did our best to explain. :(

Comment: If they're “not willing to pay” then why are you “building an application” for them? You're doing it for free? Why not write it in .NET MVC for free?

Comment: They just want it transferred to the web, with the cheapest way possible..

Comment: ...yet your question also asks "or will I have to re-write them?". It would appear you've committed to something without knowing whether it is possible. If the answer was "you have to re-write them".. would you then advise your client appropriately?

Comment: @AngelaNovak I posted an answer - just realize that the maintenance issues with running this on web tend to be more expensive than writing it correctly, at least in the long term.

Comment: Thank you all for explanations! We will act based on your responses..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to host Windows Forms content using `WindowsFormsHost` in an XBAP.  Here is [a blog post by Ahmadreza Atighechi](http://ahmadreza.com/2011/05/how-to-host-a-windows-form-application-inside-xbap/) demonstrating the process.

Note that this will require full trust to run, and likely only work in IE.  This is documented in [WPF Partial Trust Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970910.aspx), where Windows Forms Integration is listed as one of the "WPF Features that are Not Safe in Partial Trust".  This means that the default deployment for XBAP will fail when using `WindowsFormsHost`, and you'll need to make sure every system is setup to use full trust when accessing the XBAP.  The security link above describes the main issues with this.

Answer (score 1):

As far as including the entire Form within WPF or ASP.NET, I highly doubt that it's possible outside of IE; thus, alienating every other browser.

If you're still insisting to keep the current application and make it "web-like," deploy it as ClickOnce.  If that's an option, it's probably your best bet.

This allows you to include legacy controls in WPF for web...

```
<Window x:Class="HostingWfInWpf.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"  
    Title="HostingWfInWpf"
    >

    <Grid>

        <WindowsFormsHost>
            <wf:MaskedTextBox x:Name="mtbDate" Mask="00/00/0000"/>
        </WindowsFormsHost>

    </Grid>
```

From:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Anything beyond that, I wouldn't recommend at all.